# How do you create a reaction collecter which can output the names of users who reacted and save them in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make a reaction collector which will store the users who clicked on the embed so I can use them for other things and output everyone who reacted as I am making a hunger games simulator bot.

```js
if (msg.content === prefix + 'start') {
    msg.channel.send("React too the message above too join!");
    msg.react("");
    msg.awaitReactions(filter, {max: 24, time: 60000});
}
```

I currently have this code and I'm pretty sure there is a certain thing you can add but I don't know how too add it onto this and get it too collect the reactions and output them I have tried adding reaction collectors but just couldn't get them too work.

Comment: `.awaitReactions()` is not the same as `.createReactionCollector()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Message#awaitReactions` is not the same as `Message#createReactionCollector` and as you mention a reaction collector, I shall answer with an example of this.

Example:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '';
};

const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { max: 24, time: 60000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(`Collected reaction from ${user.tag}`);
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} reactions`);
});
```

`Message#createReactionCollector` has two events, `collect` and `end`, which you can listen to in order to get the number of reactions, users that reacted, and with what emoji.

The docs for this can be found [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector)

Answer (score 0):

you can check for the event when someone reacted to that message and (as I know) you can get the member object and with the fs module you can save the member's username, id etc. in a json file with `member.username` or `member.id`

Comment: Is the FS Module a NPM module? or not